# Scraping, content retrieving multiple times

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hope everything is well. I am trying to extract content under something called CEO Pay Ratio. I am gathering links to this section and sending them to a function. Now, I want the function to start gathering content from the given tag as a starting point to a thematic break as the ending point:

```py
def extract_content(soup, name):
    tag = soup.find('a', {'name': name})
    all_breaks = soup.select('hr[style*="width:100%"]')

    content = ""
    if tag:
        current_tag = tag.find_next()
        print(len(all_breaks))
        while current_tag and not (current_tag.name == 'hr' and current_tag in all_breaks):
            content += current_tag.get_text().strip() + " "
            current_tag = current_tag.find_next()

    return content.strip()
```

- all_breaks is a list of all the thematic breaks in the HTML file.

```
[<hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>, <hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>, <hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>, <hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>, .....]
```

HTML Portion I am trying to extract:

```html
<p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;"><a name="_AEIOULastRenderedPageBreakAEIOU209">
<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO"></a><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;
font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;">
<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO"></a>CEO PAY</font><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;
font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;"> RATIO</font></p>
<some other stuff>
<hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>
<some other we don't want>
```

The code I got from here:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

# preprocess the document (remove <font> tags)
for font in soup.select("font"):
    font.unwrap()

soup.smooth()

# find first tag
tag = soup.find('a', {'name':"CEO_PAY_RATIO"})

text = []
while tag := tag.next_sibling:
    if tag.name == "hr" and "width:100%" in tag.attrs.get("style", ""):
        break
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    if t:
        text.append(t)

text = "\n".join(text)
print(text)
```

This doesn't print out the content except for `CEO PAY RATIO`. But it works if the `<a name = "CEO_PAY_RATIO>` is not inside any other tag.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Maybe it appears multiple times in the file?

Comment: @ken Please [edit] your question and put there sample of the HTML file and what part are you trying to extract.

Comment: @AndrejKesely my bad. Added now.

Comment: You don't have to scrape SEC anymore. There's an [API](https://pypi.org/project/sec-api/).

Comment: Hey @baduker, I tried the API, but it just gets me the fillings. I have the fillings and I need only specific content from each filing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get the portion of the HTML document:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<p> I don't want this </p>

<p style="margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;"><a name="_AEIOULastRenderedPageBreakAEIOU209">
<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO"></a><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;
font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;">
<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO"></a>CEO PAY</font><font style="font-weight:bold;color:#0061F0;font-size:22pt;
font-family:Segoe UI;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:normal;font-variant: normal;"> RATIO</font></p>

<p> I want this </p>

<hr style="page-break-after:always;width:100%;"/>

<p> I don't want this </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

# preprocess the document (remove <font> tags)
for font in soup.select("font"):
    font.unwrap()

soup.smooth()

# find first tag
tag = soup.select_one('*:has(a[name="CEO_PAY_RATIO"]):has(~hr[style*="width:100"])')

text = [tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
while tag := tag.next_sibling:
    if tag.name == "hr" and "width:100%" in tag.attrs.get("style", ""):
        break
    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    if t:
        text.append(t)

text = "\n".join(text)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
CEO PAY RATIO
I want this
```

Comment: Hey @AndrejKesely, this isn't working when I run it over the entire HTML. It just prints out CEO_PAY_RATIO

Comment: @ken Perhaps you have multiple `<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO">` in the document? You need to locate right first tag.

Comment: Hey @AndrejKesely, the issue is the `<a name="CEO_PAY_RATIO">` is inside a <p> tag! The moment I close that p tag and start this as a separate one I am getting the data.

Comment: did that. Sorry!